# IBM DB2 native library access or small API

Tags: c, winapi, db2, database-connection

is there a simple database client library / way to access a IBM DB2 database.

I write a simple tool (c / c++) that needs to query some data from a DB2 database. I started to look for a simple library like for MySQL (e.g. a vew dll-files) but I only find the huge "DB2 Express-C server" (> 300 MB) or other IBM products... Is there a other way to connect a native (no Java) application to a DB2 Server without installing such huge packages?

- there is the php-libary (dll) : is it possible to direct use this libary or does this libary request also the whole DB2 installation?
- is there a small redistributable pack
- may I only need to copy some files out of the "DB2 Express-C server" instalation?

thank you :-)

Comment: An ODBC connection does not appeal to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute minimum required to run an ODBC (CLI) application is the IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI. For development you will need to install the IBM Data Server Client, which includes the necessary header files. An appropriate version of either can be [downloaded from here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878).

Comment: In addition, you can create a response file tuned for your requirements to install the IBM Data server Driver for ODBC. This will make a smaller foot-print or you can use db2iprune.

Comment: For db2iprune: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0025270.html and the best practices for Deploying IBM DB2 products: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Wc9a068d7f6a6_4434_aece_0d297ea80ab1/page/Deploying%20IBM%20DB2%20Products

Comment: For the response file: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0054554.html

Comment: thank you... it seams that i only was confused with the IBM homepage and all this versions :-)

Comment: If you are connecting to DB2 for i (f.k.a. AS/400, iSeries, i5) you should the driver from IBM i Access (System i Access, iSeries Access) with a version at least as high as the target server, with service pack applied.